# Wp query by 2 meta field - check if they exists / have value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am looking for the shortest most resrouce affective (not mysql query)
to count the amount of posts that have 2 meta keys <-- if they exists

i found this simple way at the codex
but it checks for values and not keys.

Also it doesnt check if key exists which
is basicly what i need since i dont know
upfront what the value is

**The example query i found in the codex looks like this:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'somepostype',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'fname'.$userid,
            'value' => 'WHATEVER',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'lname'.$userid,
            'value' => 'WHATEVER',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
return $tempquery->found_posts;
```

.
So... how can i turn that "whatever" value into a non
binding value since i only need to check if it has any
value aka the keys exists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) `meta_query` accepts an `EXISTS` comparison.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'somepostype',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'fname'.$userid,
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'lname'.$userid,
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
return $tempquery->found_posts;
```

There is a note that...

> Note: Due to bug #23268, value is required for `NOT EXISTS` comparisons
>   to work correctly. You must supply some string for the value parameter
>   - Note: empty string or NULL do NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using `NOT EXISTS`.

It sounds as though `EXISTS` is not effected but I have not tested that. However, you may need to add a placeholder `value` if that still doesn't work.

Comment: oops, ;) i completely missed that (And i looked) - thanks a lot mate.

Comment: p.s - thanks for the extra information - it helped solve this ;)